# date и datetime gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

В ms sql есть поле `DateOf` типа `date`, в нем содержатся записи формата `11.03.2016`. При выводе в gridview получается `11.03.2016 0:00:00`. Как сделать вывод как в базе? GridView генерируется автоматически.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DateOf" DataFormatString="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

Comment: Найдите где этот гридвью сгенерен автоматически и измените колонку так

Comment: И больше не пользуйтесь автогенерацией компонент